# React project - Moment Timezone has no data for Europe/London

Tags: javascript, reactjs, moment-timezone

I am using moment-timezone in a React project and after installing moment-timezone with

```
yarn add moment-timezone
```

my project had this entry in the package.json library. After testing locally the moment-timezone separately in a js file which I ran with node everything seemed to be ready to go ahead and start using the library in React.

This is by the way my experimentation script in which I create a moment object with Los Angeles time and convert it to other time zones:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
const timeLA = moment().tz("Europe/London").format();
console.log(timeLA);

const sampleMoment = moment('2020-07-06T10:00');

console.log(sampleMoment.tz("Europe/London").format());
console.log(sampleMoment.tz("Europe/Vienna").format());

const sampleMoment2 = moment.tz('2020-07-06 10:00', "America/Los_Angeles");
console.log('2020-07-06T10:00', "where you are", sampleMoment2.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format());
console.log('2020-07-06T10:00', "London", sampleMoment2.tz("Europe/London").format());
console.log('2020-07-06T10:00', "Lisbon", sampleMoment2.tz("Europe/Lisbon").format());
```

So I went to import moment-timezone in my project with:

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";
```

and wrote a factory function using this library:

```
function momentFactory(dateExpr, timezone) {
    return timezone ? moment.tz(dateExpr, timezone) : moment(dateExpr);
}
```

After my React page restart I started seeing these errors (more than 100):

> Moment Timezone has no data for America/New_York. See
>   http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.

This is quite weird because in my previous experiment just by importing the library I would have data for all possible time zones. I have no clue why something that works well in a pure node environment will not work the same way on the browser.

As a workaround I ended up by loading in my function the timezone data, but I guess this is a kind of a hack:

```
function momentFactory(dateExpr, timezone) {
    moment.tz.load(require('moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json'));
    return timezone ? moment.tz(dateExpr, timezone) : moment(dateExpr);
}
```

Is there a way to load the library properly without this workaround in a project which was bootstrapped by create-react-app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your import statement to:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data';
```

Or if you prefer the truncated smaller data set:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range';
```

(You can use any of the data files from the [builds](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/tree/develop/builds) directory.)

Also, if you are creating a new application, and targeting modern web browsers, please consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead of Moment.  Luxon is in the Moment family, but provides an immutable API, modern packaging features, and uses the built-in time zone data from modern browsers rather than requiring you to distribute time zone data with your application.  Please use Moment only if you are already using it in a legacy application, or if you require support for older web browsers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use moment.js in react you need to use `react-moment`.

Check out the link I guess this will solve your problem. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment

Comment: I am aware about `react-moment`. But I decided against using it, because I wanted to use plain javascript and not the react tags. It is an alternative, I agree, but still I wanted to know why the timezone information is not loaded without the workaround described in the question and the usage between the non react and react version differs.